# multiple has_many-through to same polymorphic table, but with different source class, fails in tests but work in reality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, has-many-through, has-many-polymorphs

The model is a `User`, which has many `Contact`s. `Post`s and `Image`s can be published to  `Contact`s through a `ContactPublishment`.

`User` has the methods `visible_posts` and `visible_images` to allow easy access to `Post`s and `Image`s published to.

The problem is that while `user.visible_images` and `user.visible_posts` work perfectly, specs that rely on these relations are going crazy:

If removing either the test for `visible_images` or `visible_posts` from the spec, the remaining tests pass. if I leave both, the 2nd one fails. I can switch the order of the tests, but still the 2nd one fails. weird huh?

This is the code sample, using Rails 3.2.15:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :visible_posts, through: :contact_publishments, source: :publishable, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :visible_images, through: :contact_publishments, source: :publishable, source_type: 'Image'
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :represented_user, class_name: User.name
  has_many :contact_publishments
end

class ContactPublishment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :publishable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contact_publishments, as: :publishable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_publishments
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contact_publishments, as: :publishable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_publishments
end


describe User do
  ...
  it "#visible_images" do
    user = create :user
    image = create :image
    image.contacts << create(:contact, represented_user: user)
    user.visible_images.should == [image]
  end

  it "#visible_posts" do
    user = create :user
    post = create :post
    post.contacts << create(:contact, represented_user: user)
    user.visible_posts.should == [post]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it eventually, but not in the way I wanted. I just wrote a manual join query. The funny thing is that this triggers the same exact SQL query that my original solution triggered, but somehow only this one passes specs. Bug in Rails?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  [Post, Image].each do |publishable|
    define_method("visible_#{publishable.name.pluralize.underscore}") do
      publishable.joins(:users).where('users.id' => self.id)
    end
  end
end
```